# PHPEXCEL fórmula que no se calcula, devuelve 0

Tags: php, funciones, phpexcel, function

Estoy intentando escribir un archivo `xls` desde `php` usando **PHPEXCEL** y tengo una columna con una fórmula que usa la función `MIN`, la cual debe devolverme el número menor de entre `3` celdas que le paso por parámetro.

El problema es que sólo calcula algunas de las celdas de esa columna, pero si falta uno de los `3` parámetros la celda tiene un `0`, sin embargo si hago `doble click` en la celda y después pulso `intro` aparece el valor calculado de la fórmula.

He probado a poner varias fórmulas del tipo sumar `3+5` o usar la función `ROUND` y todo eso funciona, pero esta fórmula no.

Pongo el código a continuación:

```
//uso la libreria PHPExcel
 require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
 require 'Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/Functions.php';

 //creo un nuevo objeto de la clase PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

for($fila=3; $fila <= $filaFinal; $fila++){//recorro las filas del xls e inserto la fórmula
       $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(73+$longitud,$fila,'=IF(MIN('.$campo1.''.$fila.','.$campo2.''.$fila.','.$campo3.''.$fila.')<>0,MIN('.$campo1.''.$fila.','.$campo2.''.$fila.','.$campo3.''.$fila.'),"")');
    }

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="ClasificacionArticulos.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    //creo un objeto para escribir los datos
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);

    //guardo los datos
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda